# Why do shared network drives, mounted on my mac, have icons vary depending on how I mount them?

Tags: network, airport, disk-volume

I have a single drive that is shared via the usb on my airport extreme. Works great.

That single drive actually has two partitions.  I use them for different reasons. (movies and stuff on one, backup on another.)

That's just background. My question is, when I mount these drives, the WAY that I mount them makes them have different icons!

-- If I have them automatically get mounted by means of having the volume be one of the startup items (in control panel->users) then it looks like a greyish blue drive with little people holding hands. BUTTT if I mount one manually, myself, by going to Go -> Network ... the icon looks brighter blue and has the wifi symbol on it.

See this picture! Both are from the same drive, but simply loaded via a different command! What is the significance ... or the "why" ... of those two different icons?

[image: the shared drive icons... varying]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since asking why Apple does something is off topic. If you can edit this to be about what specifically you want to do - it's likely we can answer this for you without waiting for an interview or public statement by Apple as to why this decision or code choice was made.